# Is there any way to play Star Wars: The Old Republic on Mac?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

My question is as stated above. I tried going the Boot Camp option but ran into too many issues and don't like the requirement of having to boot into a different OS on startup. I've also tried VMWare Fusion but the game is extremely laggy, and it's not a matter of my specs because I can run other similar games natively on my Mac with no issues.

Comment: SWTOR is an EA game. Have you tried using the Origin launcher?

Comment: The wiki states the game is only available for Windows.

Comment: Perhaps asking in the Ask Different site about the exact problems you're having with Boot Camp could help (not specifically about running swtor, but rather the general problems you've run into with Boot Camp)

Comment: On Linux, WINE needs to be patched to run SWTOR without crashing when you use or mouse over the map; not sure about Mac.  It's either specs or OSX that makes it unplayably laggy in a virtual machine -- I can play it pretty well in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to successfully install and play SWTOR using a virtual machine called [PlayOnMac](https://www.playonmac.com/en/). PlayOnMac is free and is based on a the Wine VM.

After installing PlayOnMac, there is a link in the app to install a new application. There are quite a few games in the list, SWTOR being one of them. Install SWTOR from there and start the app up. Initially, the patch process will take a few hours to get all the assets and code down to get SWTOR up to date with the latest version. (I would recommend NOT using a wireless connection for those updates. It took a long time with a wired connection.)

Playing the game has been fine with PlayonMac. I have not noticed any performance issues.